# MYSQL How to select month name in cyrillic as part of curdate () function

Tags: mariadb, locale, cyrillic

I have this Maria DB in

```
SELECT @@lc_time_names = en_US
```

I can't change it, still i need to do this

```
select date_format(CURDATE(),'%d.%M.%Y')=09.August.2018
```

Only the month name to be in cyrillic ( i.e. Август).

Any ideas how to achieve it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Can at least temporarily change `lc_time_names` variable in the session?:

```sql
MariaDB [_]> SELECT VERSION();
+-------------------------+
| VERSION()               |
+-------------------------+
| 10.3.8-MariaDB-1:10.3.8 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_lc_time_names`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DELIMITER //

MariaDB [_]> CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_lc_time_names`(`_locale` CHAR(5))
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE `_current_lc_time_names` CHAR(5)
    ->     DEFAULT @@SESSION.lc_time_names;
    -> 
    ->   SET @@SESSION.lc_time_names := `_locale`;
    ->   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d.%M.%Y');
    ->   SET @@SESSION.lc_time_names := `_current_lc_time_names`;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DELIMITER ;

MariaDB [_]> SELECT @@SESSION.lc_time_names;
+-------------------------+
| @@SESSION.lc_time_names |
+-------------------------+
| en_US                   |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [_]> CALL `sp_lc_time_names`('bg_BG');
+------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d.%M.%Y') |
+------------------------------------+
| 01.август.2000                     |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SELECT @@SESSION.lc_time_names;
+-------------------------+
| @@SESSION.lc_time_names |
+-------------------------+
| en_US                   |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```